# sqlite tables with invalid types

Tags: sqlite

I was doing something like this

```
create table company(id int primary key, name tt, time aaaa);
```

and sqlite is not throwing any errors.

I can also do the insert statements

```
insert into company2 values (1,'fff','eee');
```

Can someone explain why it is like this?

Comment: Did you check the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html)?  The rules for data types are quite "liberal".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).
This behaviour is by design.

Also see the [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3).